# When is a floating point operation 'invalid'?

Tags: c++, boost, precision, numeric

Consider (both msvc15 and 16 i.e. Visual Studio 2017 & 2019) on a Xeon 15something:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int x;
    uint8_t val;
    float f;

    x = _status87();    // x = 0 here, OK
    f = -1.00e+9;
    x = _status87();    // x = 0 here, OK
    val = uint8_t(f);   // val = 0 here, I can live with that
    x = _status87();    // x = 0 here, OK
    f = -1.00e+10;
    val = uint8_t(f);   // val = 0 here, I can live with that
    x = _status87();    // x = 16 = _EM_INVALID, wtf?
}
```

It's obvious that some casts give the 'wrong' result, i.e. when you want to store a number that is more than what fits in a variable of a certain type, there is no way to store that value. My question is - why is the status flag of the floating point register set to 'invalid'? Over/underflow and/or inexact I could live with, by why 'invalid'? I can't find any definition anywhere of what specific CPU's consider 'invalid' floating point operations. I also can't find out why, with a mantissa 9 this register is not set (despite the value not fitting and the cast result being 0), but with a mantissa 10 it *is* flagged. It seems to me that no relevant maximum/minimum is being passed at that threshold.

More importantly (to me), is there a way for me to cast in a way so that the floating point register isn't touched, ever? The reason being that the code I'm working on relies (later on) on the register not being in an 'invalid' state, and I can't reasonably or reliably modify each use of that register flag check. But also just resetting the flag is error-prone (because of assumptions elsewhere, 'elsewhere' being code I can't touch). I've been looking at boost::numeric_cast but that doesn't seem to help any here, unless I'm missing something somewhere?

But in general, any help on how 'invalid' floating point operations work would be helpful.

Comment: _"I can't find any definition anywhere of what specific CPU's consider 'invalid' floating point operations. "_ - as per IEEE-754 the _invalid_ exception is typically the result of NaN being produced by an arithmetic operation. I don't see this in the example above, however, so this may be some hardware specific trap being in effect instead. See e.g. [Oracle's Numerical Computation Guide's summary of IEEE 754 exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_handle.html) for details.

Comment: @dfri Yes that's indeed one of the few pages I found Googling that mentions this, but I figured this would be largely specific to SPARC processors and if not, certainly specific to the old Sun compilers; I'm not sure that page is still very relevant in 2020?

Comment: That page condenses relevant parts of IEEE-754, which is not required by the ISO C++ Standard, but which many (most modern?) architectures implements.

Comment: Your program has _undefined behavior_, therefore it can do whatever it wants. See my answer for details.

Comment: C ++ or boost have nothing to do with this. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttss2si

Comment: @dfri It is not required, but if `numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` is true (which it usually is) IEEE 754 is promised. The true issue is probably that either there are cases not covered by IEEE 754 or compiler writers/standard writers/cpu implementors do not care for 100% IEEE 754 conformance with (rarely used) corner cases where one then has (unintentional) deviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/5znx1e), we can see that for the conversion is used the instruction `cvttss2si`. The [documentation for this instruction reads](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttss2si):

> Converts a single-precision floating-point value in the source operand (the second operand) **to a signed double-word integer** (or signed quadword integer if operand size is 64 bits) in the destination operand (the first operand).

Since the register used there is `eax`, the double-word case applies here. Next, there is written:

> If a converted result **is larger than the maximum signed doubleword integer, the floating-point invalid exception is raised**.

In your case, -1e9 can be stored in a signed double word, but -1e10 cannot. The exception is then seemingly just translated into the status register read by `_status87()` function.

---

Note that the behavior is **undefined** according to the C++ Standard here according to [conv.fpint/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1):

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type**.

This holds for both values of `f`.

Comment: Ah yes that fully explains it, thanks. I guess I'll just have to put my data in a double first, check that the value doesn't exceed the min/max of the type I'm casting to, and only then cast (my real code is happening inside a template which obscured what was happening in my real code).

Comment: @Roel -- the issue here isn't the **cast** (which isn't needed, except to silence busybody compilers), but the **conversion**. That is, `val = f;` would present the same problem.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but in this case it's a distinction without a difference. Thanks.